# Sending objective-c object to js?

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c, ios, webkit

I'm actually doing an UIWebview with html and js in it.
A friend doing same with Android

My problem is that on android, there is a way to just send an Android object to the javascript and use it easily in it

But is there a way to do the same in iOS ?

I tried to use windowScriptObject but its not available on iphone.
I also tried to send all the datas one per one with

```
stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString
```

but it's kinda ugly :/

Is there other solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On iOS the only way is to use stringByEvaluatinfJavaScriptFromString.

But why are you calling the data one by one? Package them up into your own data structure, or using Jason is a easy and natural way for passing data to Javascript.

Comment: Do you have an sample code or a link ? because i don't really see how i can send my own data structure oO. will it be recognized by javascript ?

Comment: A few people have example projects on the web doing this sort of thing, I'll see if I can find one using JSON that I saw a few months ago an post the link.

Comment: Have a look at this and change it to your needs https://github.com/ochameau/NativeBridge

Comment: Thanks i'll look at this sample ! Hope i'll find what i want x)

Answer (score 0):

You [can do it if you use Webkit](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/30001215-BBCBFJCD).  The docs on [using WebKit from an Objective-C program](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DisplayWebContent/DisplayWebContent.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000164-SW1) are here

Comment: It's for iPhone and when i try to use windowScriptObject it say, "instance method not found"

Comment: You might be out of luck then.  I can understand that Apple would make it difficult to execute Objective-C code from Javascript because of security concerns.